# Ancient texts on Karnavedha

Tags: vedas, practice, vedic-rituals, manuscripts

Are there any quotes from ancient texts that talk about Karnavedha?

Although there are various reasons that are cited to justify it as in it helps regulate menstruation in women, or that it helps in the regulated flow of the etheric forces through the body and so on. I have also heard that susrutha had mentioned when, how and why ear piercing must be done.

Where can I find texts relating to this.

I know this question had been asked before but there were no answers so posting again.

Appreciate your help.